# Canonical way of denoting the set of all (totally) ordered subsets

Tags: combinatorics, notation, convention

Given a **finite** set $S$, we usually denote the set of all subsets of $S$ by $\mathcal{P}(S)$, i.e. the *power set* of $S$.

I need to denote the set of all *totally ordered* subsets of $S$, let us call it $\mathcal{T}(S)$. That is, elements of $\mathcal{T}(S)$ are all tuples $(A, \leq_A)$ with $A \in \mathcal{P}(S)$ and $\leq_A$ a total order on $A$. This is also the same as the subset of $S^*$ (all sequences of elements from $S$) which do not contain repeated elements.

I have a feeling that this is so common that there must be a canonical notation for $\mathcal{T}(S)$, just as $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is the canonical way of denoting the power set of $S$?

Comment: Ah, I assumed that $S$ was finite, and hence $A$ will also be finite, implying that $\leq_A$ is indeed a well-ordering. I'm not sure what you mean by "tuples" vs "ordered pairs", but what I meant was that the elements of $\mathcal{T}(S)$ are just the (finite) subsets $A$ of $S$ equipped with a total order $\leq_A$, which I denoted by $(A, \leq_A)$. Hope that made sense :)

Comment: No problem, I think I'll emphasize it in the question :).